# Postgresql-Patroni-Etcd election handicapping

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, etcd, patroni

I am planning the creation of a PostgreSQL HA cluster that spans multiple data centres on different continents and trying to figure out how to tweak the election parameters in etcd and patron so that we are unlikely to failover accidentally to a continent from our app servers unless the databases closer to the application servers are down.

So far in my research I have concluded that I should be able to tweak the election timeout settings in etc so that the variance between the servers is less than the latency of the intercontinental hop.  This should help on the etcd side with helping to prevent far-away servers deciding to take over.  However.... how do I prevent the same on the Patroni side?  Is there a best practice for handicapping servers we want to avoid being put into the master role?